# ArrayList Error, Tic-Tac-Toe Non-Functional Bug

Tags: java, random, arraylist, seed

Hi I've been attempting to make my first AI for a small game I'm making and I need help with a game I'm currently coding.  It contains a seed class, in that it takes a number as parameters for the length of the ArrayList it returns.  The ArrayList then is comprised of consecutive numbers that are randomized out of order.  The only problem is that although it appears to work, at some points the Computer will make no choice at all, shifting back to the user's turn.  There seems to be some problem during the translation from the ArrayList to the Object calling it.  Here's what I have in the class so far:

```
package ttt;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Seed
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> seed;
    public Seed(int num)
    {
        seed = new ArrayList<Integer>(num);
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            seed.add(i);
        generateSeed();
    }
    public void generateSeed()
    {
        Collections.shuffle(seed);
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getSeed()
    {
        return seed;
    }
}
```

And here is the block of code that it returns to(I understand it is lengthy but I just thought that including the entire thing might be helpful):

```
if(difficulty == 2)
        {
            seed.generateSeed();
            ArrayList<Integer> random = seed.getSeed();
            //It is within this for loop and the for loop following it that I believe the bug occurs.
            for(int i = 0; i < random.size(); i++)
            {
                if(random.get(i) == 1)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[0][1] == 1 && set[0][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 2)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[1][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 3)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 1 && set[2][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 4)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][0] == 1 && set[2][0] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 5)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 1 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][1] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 6)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][2] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 7)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 8)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][0] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 9)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 1 && set[0][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 10)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[1][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 11)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 12)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 1 && set[2][0] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 13)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][1] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 14)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 1 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 15)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 16)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][0] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 17)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 18)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 19)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 1 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 20)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 21)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 22)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 23)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(i) == 24)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 1)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < random.size(); j++)
            {
                if(random.get(j) == 1)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[0][1] == 2 && set[0][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 2)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[1][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 3)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 2 && set[2][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 4)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][0] == 2 && set[2][0] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 5)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 2 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][1] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 6)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][2] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 7)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 8)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][0] == 0)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 9)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 2 && set[0][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 10)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[1][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 11)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 12)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 2 && set[2][0] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 13)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][1] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 14)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 2 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 15)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 16)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][0] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 17)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 18)
                {
                    if(set[1][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 19)
                {
                    if(set[2][0] == 2 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 2;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 20)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 0;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 21)
                {
                    if(set[0][1] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 22)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 2;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 23)
                {
                    if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
                if(random.get(j) == 24)
                {
                    if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 2)
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        set[x][y] = 2;
                        return new int[] {x, y};
                    }
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 1 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 2;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 1 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 1 && set[0][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[1][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 2;
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 1 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][1] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 1 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 1)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 1)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
            {
                x = 2;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 1)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 1)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 1)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 1)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 2 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 2;
                y = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2) + 1;
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 2 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 2 && set[0][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[1][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 2;
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    y = 0;
                else
                    y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 2 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][1] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                if(g.nextInt(2) == 1)
                    x = 0;
                else
                    x = 2;
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 2 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 2)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 2)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
            {
                x = 2;
                y = g.nextInt(2);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 2)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 2)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(2);
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 2)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 2)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(2);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }

            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[0][1] == 0 && set[0][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[1][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[2][0] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = 2;
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][0] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(3);
                y = 0;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][1] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][1] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(3);
                y = 1;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][2] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                x = g.nextInt(3);
                y = 2;
                set[x][y] = 2;
                return new int[] {x, y};
            }
            if(set[0][0] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][2] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(3);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 2)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            if(set[0][2] == 0 && set[1][1] == 0 && set[2][0] == 0)
            {
                dig = g.nextInt(3);
                if(dig == 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 2;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 1)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y = 1;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
                if(dig == 2)
                {
                    x = 2;
                    y = 0;
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
            while(true && !(checkComplete()))
            {
                x = g.nextInt(3);
                y = g.nextInt(3);
                if(set[x][y] == 0)
                {
                    set[x][y] = 2;
                    return new int[] {x, y};
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered a more elegant approach? I taught some students once how to code a tic tac toe AI, and we learned that all you need to do is a small set of rules before you get ideal game play. Nowhere near as complicated as this.

Comment: The only reason it is this complicated is that I simply made it so any possible row you input from will have an appropriate counter, such as the computer blocking off your row or auto-completing theirs.  There probably is a more efficient way to do it using more logic, but I just took the safe route and did it like this.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](http://xkcd.com/832/).

Comment: Look at the [Tic Tac Toe strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy)

Comment: The funny part is that that's exactly what I did.  Funny I haven't seen that particular comic yet though, I always see his posts floating around the web.  But either way, does anyone know any reason why the ArrayList is causing this bug?

Comment: What bug? Please describe your exception or error, because you've posted a lot of code.

Comment: Every once in a while during any game, but not always, only certain games, after the user makes his choice and completes his turn, the computer will just completely skip its turn and the user will be allowed to make a second turn in a row.  So far, the two coordinates I've recorded this occuring at are [0,2] and [2,0].

Comment: I would really recommend you to approach this program from another way. It is not that hard.

Comment: Could you give a suggestion?  I don't mean to sound clueless but in looking at the logic of the strategy that you linked, it seems that any other way to make a human equivalent AI would be equally as complicated.

Comment: After debugging a bit, I haven't figured out how to fix it or why it isn't working correctly, but I have figured out what it is doing.  Even though the space is already filled in by the computer, it is deciding to fill the space in again anyway wasting its turn.  I guess the only thing to do now is review each if statement and see where certain points may intersect.